# TeX Gyre Pagella and itemize environment gives font warnings

Tags: fonts, symbols, pdftex, warnings

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tgpagella}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item test1
    \item test2
    \item test3
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Compiling the above minimal LaTeX file with a fresh installation of **TeX Live 2011** on Linux gives the following warnings:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/qpl/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead
(Font)              for symbol `textbullet' on input line 7.
...
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

It works absolutely fine with the default Computer Modern fonts.

It seems like this is just a problem with `tgpagella` not defining its own bullet symbols. What is the best way to deal with this sort of warning? Can it be safely ignored and is there a way to stop it appearing every time I compile (without disabling other warnings)? It's especially annoying when using Vim because the focus moves to the error window every time I compile the document!

Comment: Add `\usepackage{textcomp}`; the problem would be there with almost all other font packages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Load the [`textcomp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/textcomp) package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tgpagella}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item test1
    \item test2
    \item test3
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This fixes it! So does tgpagella depend on the symbols defined by textcomp? If so, why doesn't it include it itself?! Thanks a lot!

Comment: LaTeX is set up for getting the bullet from the math symbol font. So when a font family doesn't have a companion math symbol font, LaTeX issues a warning. I believe that Vim's behavior can be changed to ignore such warnings.

Comment: @egreg In that case, why does also including a maths font (e.g. mathpazo - before tgpagella of course) not prevent this warning? Also, any clues on the Vim configuration? The Vim-Latex documentation is pretty difficult to get through!

Comment: @mjrussel The warning tells you that the font combination `OMS/qpl/m/n` doesn't exist. The math fonts for `mathpazo` are not connected with TeX Gyre Pagella. Indeed, if you use only `mathpazo`, the warning is not produced. Why doesn't that package load `textcomp`? No font package that I know of does it.

Comment: i wonder if there's a way to (as it were) load a ts1 encoding for use whenever it's available.  that way, the textcomp substitutions could step in in place of the maths symbols whenever it might be useful.