# Itemize & italic with [utopia]{mathdesign}

Tags: fonts, italic, mathdesign

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TeX Gyre Pagella and itemize enviroment gives font warnings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46129/tex-gyre-pagella-and-itemize-enviroment-gives-font-warnings)

I'm using `\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}`. When I include an `itemize` environment inside a `{\itshape ...}` section, the following warnings are produced:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/mdput/m/it' undefined
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

What should I be doing instead?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}

{\itshape
\begin{itemize}
    \item Foo!
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a MWE?

Comment: @egreg I need to remember to minimize my document before even asking the question... turns out it wasn't a problem with math but with `itemize`. Probably the bullets.

Comment: `\usepackage{textcomp}` is your friend.

Comment: @jtbandes It is essentially the same problem as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46129/tex-gyre-pagella-and-itemize-enviroment-gives-font-warnings, which is solved by `\usepackage{textcomp}`.